# Expo version 47 causing "TypeError: (...) is not a function.... is an instance of Object)." But I know it is a function

Tags: expo

The npm package 'native-notify' works fine in Expo version 46. But in Expo version 47, I get this error:

```
TypeError: (0, _nativeNotify.default) is not a function. (In '(0, _nativeNotify.default)(5168, 'CDQ7qgg9m0awOxaMtMlK6r')', '(0, _nativeNotify.default)' is an instance of Object)
```

What is wrong? Why do I get this error in Expo version 47?

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused. I tried creating a new app from scratch. I did nothing different. It worked this time. I'm wondering if it has to do with an issue with the new M1 chip I'm using and the Expo Go app and the new Expo 47 being used with the new React Native 70. I have no idea.

If anyone else has had any experience like this, please comment to let me know this is a normal occurrence.